# $A_4={2,3}, B={1,2,3,4,5,6}$. Verify if $(A_4\times B)\cap (B\times A_4)=A_4 \times A_4$ and $(A_4\times B)\cup(B\times A_4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$A_4={2,3}, B={1,2,3,4,5,6}$
Verify if $(A_4\times B)\cap (B\times A_4)=A_4 \times A_4$ and $(A_4\times B)\cup(B\times A_4)$

Just making sure my logic is correct. Make sure I didn't do anything wrong.

$A_4$={2,3}
B={1,2,3,4,5,6}
$A_4\times B$={{2,1}{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{3,1}{3,2},{3,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6}}
$B\times A_4$={{1,2},{1,3},{2,2},{2,3},{3,2},{3,3},{4,2},{4,3},{5,2},{5,3},{6,2},{6,3}}
$A_4\times A_4$={{2,2},{2,3},{3,2},{3,3}}
$B\times B$={{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{4,1},{4,2},{4,3},{4,4},{4,5},{4,6},{5,1},{5,2},{5,3},{5,4},{5,5},{5,6},{6,1},{6,2},{6,3},{6,4},{6,5},{6,6}}
$(A_4\times B)\cap(B\times A_4)$={{2,2},{2,3},{3,2},{3,3}}
$(A_4 \times B)\cup(B\times A_4)$={{1,2},{1,3},{2,1}{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{3,1}{3,2},{3,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{4,2},{4,3},{5,2},{5,3},{6,2},{6,3}}
Therefore
$(A_4\times B)\cap(B\times A_4)=A_4\times A_4$
$(A_4\times B)\cup(B\times A_4)!=B\times B$

Comment: Yes.... but you could probably reason it out with a lot less listing.  Not:  $(m,n) = A \times B\cap B\times A$ iff $m$ and $n$ are both in both $A,B$ so $A\times B \cap B\times A = (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap B)$  And as $A\cap B = A$ this holds.